# Динамический Layout React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, layout

подскажите пожалуйста, вопрос такой
у меня есть layout, в зависимости от роута меняется содержимое layout
но есть в этом layout еще одно место, постоянное, то есть например правая колонка, но тут уже внутренность этой правой колонки которая в layout, тоже меняется, в зависимости от роута, то есть разные компоненты и тд и тп, в зависимости от роута

такое можно реализовать, оставляя подход решения через layout?